# Tab size fixed to 8 in spite of polyglot.

Tags: tab-characters, plugin-vim-polyglot

I am using Vim 8. Since I installed vim-polyglot to handle syntax highlighting and indentation of different languages without going crazy, whatever file I open has a tab size of 8 automatically. I know that I could change the tab size manually for every filetype but I thought the purpose of polyglot was not to have to do that. Any help or alternative?

Comment: May be interested in [editor-config](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) or [sleuth.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim-polyglot is mainly a collection of different filetype and syntax specific plugins. However, setting the tab size is usually a user setting, that should not be set by any filetype plugin. So if you want a different tab size, I suggest to set it in your .vimrc or inside you own filetype plugins (alternatively use FileType autocommands). See also the [faq question 26.1](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.1) and following questions.